# MySQL: testing performance after dividing a table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I made a test to see if dividing an indexed large table will increase the performance.

Original Table: 20000 rows.
Sub Tables: 4x5000 rows.

The main Table is divided into 4 tables, all tables are indexed, in the test each sql query was executed 10000 times in a loop to measure more accurate query times.

When I search an indexed column in the table, I see no difference in performance and Query times are the same for the original (20000 Rows) table and the new (5000 rows) tables.

I tried the same test without indexing by deleting indexes for all tables, and the difference in performance was obvious, where searching in sub tables was 6 times faster than searching in the large table. But with indexing the performance was the same.

So do you think it is a waste of time to divide my tables into smaller ones?

Note: 20000 size is just for testing, my real data will be of the size of 100M or more.

Comment: Table structure should be determined by the needs of the application and what makes logical sense.  Especially on a table size of 20,000 records which is already tiny.  (row size limit is 65,535 bytes so even if you're maxing that out the data size isn't all that much)

Comment: it is a waste of time!

Comment: The sample table is for test, real data will be much larger than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a waste of time.  Databases can easily handle millions of rows and 20,000 is relatively small.  As you noticed, indexes make finding data fast.  The size of the data doesn't affect the speed of lookups noticeably in most cases.  Queries might take a few more milliseconds if the difference in size is 100 or 1000 times, but the scale you're working on would make no real difference.

Comment: My sample table was for test only, my real data will reach 100M rows or something in that range. If your point about 100 ot 1000 times size difference is accurate, then dividing strategy will be a waste since I will not divide my table into 100 tables !.

Comment: @user2007059 That and you'd have to know which table to look in, which would be more code that wouldn't have a "good" way of knowing which table it needs.

Answer (score 0):

What you have effectively done is reinvented [Partitioning of Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html).  I would not use your own sub-table scheme and focus on using partitioned tables would automatically mean that internally subtables are used and if you formulate your SQL appropriately, subtables would automatically be excluded from operations if not needed.

However, all the management of the partitions would be on the server itself, so that your client code can be kept simple and you still only have to deal with a single table.